# Retrofit model organizing

Tags: android, retrofit

I have faced with a throwable in the `Retrofit`:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 246 path $.suggested.taxonomies[1].payload.scope.
```

What I have ?

I have a `Payload.class` which I use to get all data from api, there are a plenty of nested stuff, but what I try to implement is `LinkedTreeMap<Object, ScopeModel> scope`:

Payload.class:

```
public class Payload {

    @SerializedName("product_id")
    @Expose
    private String productId;
    @SerializedName("primary_image")
    @Expose
    private String primaryImage;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private String rating;
    @SerializedName("review_count")
    @Expose
    private String reviewCount;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("scope")
    @Expose //TODO fix this
    private LinkedTreeMap<Object, ScopeModel> scope = new LinkedTreeMap<>();
    @SerializedName("direct_link")
    @Expose
    private String directLink;
    @SerializedName("keyword")
    @Expose
    private String keyword;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getPrimaryImage() {
        return primaryImage;
    }

    public void setPrimaryImage(String primaryImage) {
        this.primaryImage = primaryImage;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getReviewCount() {
        return reviewCount;
    }

    public void setReviewCount(String reviewCount) {
        this.reviewCount = reviewCount;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public LinkedTreeMap<Object, ScopeModel> getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(LinkedTreeMap<Object, ScopeModel> scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public String getDirectLink() {
        return directLink;
    }

    public void setDirectLink(String directLink) {
        this.directLink = directLink;
    }

    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }
}
```

and `ScopeModel` which I use in the `LinkedTreeeMap`:

```
public class ScopeModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Why I use `LinkedTreeMap`? I'm not understood why (I'm newbiew in android) :D.
My logic is that: When I change `LinkedTreeMap<Object,ScopeModel> scope` to `Object scope;` in the `Payload` I found in the debugger that thing:
[image]

As I understood API returns me `LinkedTreeMap` with data which I need, because of that I try to made `ScopeModel` and etc. What can I do with my code ?

Anyway, thank you and sorry for my english!

Comment: I'm not sure to answer you since I'm not used to LikedTreeMap. could you add your json file ?

Comment: @RenaudFavier is the debugger output not enough ?

Comment: I don't understand what does your json look like, I doubt LikedTreeMap is the right type you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switch

```
@SerializedName("scope")
@Expose //TODO fix this
private LinkedTreeMap<Object, ScopeModel> scope = new LinkedTreeMap<>();
```

to

```
@SerializedName("scope")
@Expose //TODO fix this
private ScopeModel scope;
```